# Does Oculus LipSync Unity plugin work for IOS in 2023? If not, any recommended alternatives?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, oculus, lipsync

I saw it at https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Audio-SDK-Development/Oculus-Lip-Sync-not-working-with-iOS/m-p/571378

Just wondering if this is still the case now, I may have to switch to other audio to lipsync softwares if this one doesn't support my requirement

Is there any recommended softwares that does the same as Oculus lipsync and support IOS?